# GDAL tiling error for EPSG: 3857

Tags: python, web-mapping, gdal, gdalwarp

i have lots of data which was coordinated with gdal some programatic way at below:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff  -a_ullr %s %s %s %s -a_srs EPSG:3857 %s/%s  %s/%s.tif
```

then for tiling them all i am building virtual dataset with this:

```
gdalbuilvrt some.vrt *.tif
```

for getting its geographic info with gdalinfo i am getting this result:

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS[,
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (.......,.......)
Pixel Size = (4.777314268465985,-4.777314267784062)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( .....

Band 1 Block=2816x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=2816x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=2816x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

then with this virtual dataset for gettin geodeitc tile i am calling gdal2tiles.py with profil geodetic but i am getting this result:

```
ERROR 1: No PROJ.4 translation for source SRS, coordinate
transformation initialization has failed.
Generating Base Tiles:
Generating Overview Tiles:
```

where am I wrong? I haven't found yet. but when running gdal2tiles.py for only one tif file it is working and in global mapper it returns true result.

How can I tile my image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your version of GDAL doesn't have the definition for Spherical Mercator, AKA Web Mercator, AKA Google Mercator. You could try using EPSG 900913 which is the old code for 3857 - you only need to run `gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:900913 ...` on your sources.

**But ideally you should get GDAL version 1.9.0**

Comment: before your post i tried in 1.8.0 and i get rid of "unnamed", "unknown", "unretrievable" things... i know all my tif tile is as above but adding OGC WKT for 2857 to my vrt i have solved the problem...  thanks anyway